# Reference: Derivatives of Riemannian Exponential Map

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Is there a known formula expressing the (first two) derivatives of the Riemannian exponential map on a Riemmannian manifold $(M,g)$?  I keep seeing references about some type of Jacobi-field thing but I can't seem to find anything expressing both the first and the second one...could someone please provide a reference :))